# IF condition in awk command in nodetool cfstats command

Tags: linux, awk, cassandra, grep

```
$ nodetool cfstats 
  | awk '($1!="Total" && $1!~"-") {print $0}'
  | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"; -v keyspacename==""; -v tablename==""; part_max_mb==""}
    $1=="Keyspace"{
      if($3!="keyspacename"){
        if(keyspacename!="") {
          print keyspacename, tablename, part_max_mb
        }
      }
      keyspacename=$3;
      next
    }
    $1=="Table:"{
      if($2!="tablename") {
        if(tablename!="") {
          print keyspacename, tablename, part_max_mb
        }
      }
      tablename=$2;
      next
    }
    ($1=="Compacted" && $3=="maximum"){
      part_max_mb=$5/1000000
    }
    END{print keyspacename, tablename, part_max_mb}'
```

I need to print only part_max_mb > 1000 and sort it out by part_max_mb

This is the output:

---

`Keyspace_name|table_name1|129.558 Keyspace_name|table_name2|1002.0908 Keyspace_name|table_name3|7.0 Keyspace_name|table_name4|4.86632 Keyspace_name|table_name5|900 Keyspace_name|table_name6|0 Keyspace_name|table_name7|0.009887 Keyspace_name|table_name8|4139.11`

Expected output with values greater than 1000 and in descending sorting:

---

**Keyspace_name|table_name8|4139.11
Keyspace_name|table_name2|1002.0908**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, please do add your sample of input and expected output in your question to make question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Kindly do update your question, as comments are not meant for samples, thank you.